# One Queue for each Consumer - Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, producer-consumer, distributed-system

I'm in a **single-producer/multiple-consumers** scenario. Consider that each job is independent and the consumers do not communicate among them.

1. Could it be a good idea to create a different queue for each consumer?
   In that way, the producer adds jobs in each queue in a round-robin fashion and there are no delays in accessing a single queue.
2. Or is it better to minimize the number of queues as much as possible?
3. In the case of a single Queue and lots of consumers (like 20 or more), is the delay due to the synchronization access to the queue relevant?

I'm using Python 3.7 and multithreading/multiprocessing to create several Consumers. Each Consumer needs to run an executable and perform some I/O operation (write, move or copy files). I've currently developed it with multiprocessing and single queue, but I'm thinking to change the approach to multithreading and multiple queues.

Single Queue

```
                          Consumer
                        /
                       /  ..
Producer --> [ Queue ] -- Consumer
                       \  ..
                        \
                          Consumer
```

Multiple Queue

```
               -> [ Queue ] -- Consumer
             / 
            / ..
Producer ----- -> [ Queue ] -- Consumer
            \ ..
             \
               -> [ Queue ] -- Consumer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically in the case of one producer -> many consumers, the benefit is to only have 1 Queue that the producer has to connect to and you can spin up as many consumers as you want to process 'the next item'. Because Python has a very complicated relationship with Threading, I would recommend to use `asyncio` with `asyncio.Queue`. It is very intuitive and easy to use.

I recently brushed up on this topic and I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1st1/f110d5e2ade94e679c4442e9b6d117e1) very helpful in understanding how it works.

In any case, having more Queues will probably not speed up your processing. This could only be the case if (time to process message) < (get message from queue), which is not the case in your use case (with IO tasks etc).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. On the other hand, in the case of multiple producers and one consumer, could there be any significant delay in adding tasks to a single queue by many producers?

Comment: Another question: the main problem with the single-queue approach could be that every single task in the queue is quite fast (about 1 sec) to be executed. Moreover, Queue doesn't allow to get elements in chunks, so each second many Consumers try to access the queue resulting in a little delay. If this delay is multiplied by 1 million tasks, I think that the delay could be relevant. Am I right or my thought is wrong?

Comment: **Q**: what in case of many producers? **A**: Also here, it is highly, highly unlikely that putting something on a Queue would be a time consuming task. The only thing I can think of is if the Queue is full (not fast enough processed), then the producer will wait for an open spot.

Comment: **Q**: what if the tasks are fast? **A**: your logic is flawed in that case, because the overhead of getting an item from a Queue is identical from a consumer point of view. In any case, a task of 1 second is not ridiculously short, especially if it is IO bound. You would have to have hundreds of consumers in your code to hit any delay from using just one Queue.